# exec not working in expect script

Tags: exec, tcl, expect

I'm writing my first expect script, so I may be missing something obvious, but I find the following quite puzzling:

```
$ expect
expect1.1> exec echo a
a
expect1.2>
$ cat > test.exp
exec echo a
$ expect test.exp
$
```

If I run expect and make it exec something manually, it works. If I put the same command in a script, it doesn't work. What's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that expect is essentially an extension of Tcl. Tcl's `exec` executes the external command, *captures the output and returns it as a value* -- it does **not** send it to stdout unless you instruct it to. However, an *interactive* Tcl (or expect) session prints the output to stdout *as a convenience*.

Your script should be:

```
puts [exec echo a]
# or
set output [exec echo a]
puts $output
```

I'm assuming "echo a" is a placeholder for a more complicated external command. If you just want to print something:

```
puts "this is something"  ;# the Tcl way
send_user "this is too\n" ;# the expect way
```

If you're new to Tcl as well as expect then you should [learn Tcl](http://www.msen.com/~clif/TclTutor.html) first.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You're right, I'm also new to Tcl. To be perfectly honest, I'm not looking to learn how to program in Tcl; I just wanted to solve a practical problem, and expect sounded like the right tool for the job. Perhaps this kind of effort is more suited for superuser.com.

Comment: @LaC, I suggested learning Tcl (it doesn't take long) because it will make your expect programming *tons* easier.

Comment: One more thing: do not wrap the command using "".  Otherwise, it will fail.  At least, it failed in my case.